# CSS3 animation to create an accordion panel

Tags: css, accordion, css-animations

I have this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6XXC/)** where I'm trying to create an accordion purely with CSS3 and animations.

The setup is fairly simple: a checkbox (with state checked or unchecked) controls whether the content div should be collapsed or not. The checkbox is hidden and controlled by the label.

This principle works fine, the animation however does not. All I want is the div to slide open and closed.

### HTML

```
<div class="accordeon">
    <input type="checkbox" name="accordeon-title" class="accordeon-checkbox" id="accordeon-title" /><label for="accordeon-title" class="accordeon-title-label">Accordeon titel</label>
    <div class="accordeon-content">
        Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS3

```
 /*Init*/
    .accordeon-checkbox {display: none;}
    .accordeon-title-label {cursor: pointer; background: #c4c4c4; display: block;}
    .accordeon-content {height: 0; overflow:hidden; line-height: 0;}

    /*Click functionaliteit*/
    .accordeon:checked + label {background: #e4e4e4;}
    .accordeon-checkbox:checked ~ .accordeon-content {  
        -webkit-animation: slide-up 5s; /* Safari 4+ */
        -moz-animation:    slide-up 5s; /* Fx 5+ */
        -o-animation:      slide-up 5s; /* Opera 12+ */
        animation:         slide-up 5s; /* IE 10+ */

        -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;
        -moz-animation-timing-function:ease;
        -o-animation-timing-function:ease;
        animation-timing-function:ease;

        line-height: inherit; overflow: visible; height: 100%;
    }   

    /*Animation functionality*/
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
        0%   { height: 0; }
        100% { height: 100%; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-up {
        0%   { height: 0; }
        100% { height: 100%; }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-up {
        0%   { height: 0; }
        100% { height: 100%; }
    }
    @keyframes slide-up {
        0%   { height: 0; }
        100% { height: 100%; }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please note that **once** the checkbox is checked, you are re-setting the `height`, `line-height` and `overflow` properties. Hence the animation doesn't have any effect in this case.

Also, `height: 100%` doesn't affect the element as its parent doesn't have an explicit `height`. So you'll need to use a fixed value for height property.

In addition, CSS animation is unable to [animate the `overflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378517/css-animation-wont-work-with-overflow-hidden) property, and `line-height` **properly** (specially by `inherit` value).

In order to stop the animation at the end keyframe, you should use [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property with `forwards` value.

Here is the shorthand version:

```css
.accordeon-checkbox:checked ~ .accordeon-content {
    -webkit-animation: slide-up 1s ease forwards;
    /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation: slide-up 1s ease forwards;
    /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation: slide-up 1s ease forwards;
    /* Opera 12+ */
    animation: slide-up 1s ease forwards;
    /* IE 10+ */
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/g6XXC/1/)**.

### An issue with closing the panel

But there's an issue with using animations. Since the animation is applied to the element only when the checkbox **is checked**, Once you uncheck the checkbox by the second click, the panel will be closed *immediately* **without** any animations.

Hence, it's better to use [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) to achieve the desired effect.

Here you go:

```css
.accordeon-content {
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: gold;

    /* other vendor-prefixes here... */
    transition: height 1s ease;
}

.accordeon-checkbox:checked ~ .accordeon-content {
    height: 400px;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/g6XXC/2/)**.

Comment: the problem with this is is the same with every other example like this i have seen.  you have to define height.  which in the age of responsiveness that is a no go.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew It can be done without specifying `height` explicitly, simply by animating `max-height` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/g6XXC/26/

Comment: cool. does this work with ie 9?  As well, what other limitations of this method can you think of? Like for example I see you set the max-height to 999px is that like an estimate per se?

Comment: lol and don't you think the fiddle you gave in this comment is the better answer?  to me it works better.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Yes the value is estimated. One drawback of this approach is that the value should be high enough in order not to clip the element. Actually the question was a bit different but I'll update the answer to include this approach ASAP.

Comment: In terms of responsiveness this may be ok.  The value can be over but not under correct?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Yes, it must be over. Otherwise it overrides the `height` and clips the element.